# MPI RMA communication

Tags: c, mpi

Currently I am trying to solve an identical problem with different initial conditions on multiple processors. The set up is currently with MPI and C. I want the first processor who finds a solution to signal to all the others to stop and suppress output.

How does one solve this with RMA, would I need to create a locking structure?

Comment: A solution with RMA will be complicated (and possibly more overhead). It can be done much simpler with a non-blocking wildcard receive( `MPI_Irecv` with `MPI_ANY_SOURCE`) and an `MPI_Test` once in every iteration of your application's loop.

Comment: @Arash using MPI_Ibarrier is more efficient if you want all the other processes to detect termination.

Comment: @Jeff If a process enters a barrier, how can it still make progress toward solving the problem? Please see the question one more time.... He wants to detect termination while still working...

Comment: MPI_Ibarrier is nonblocking. Please look it up. Torsten Hoefler has a paper showing how to use it for asynchronous termination detection.

Comment: http://htor.inf.ethz.ch/publications/index.php?pub=99

Comment: Oops. I missed the I in MPI_Ibarrier... yep you are right.